# Getting an ORA-01426: Numeric Overflow in .NET 4.0, C#, using the Oracle DataAccess .dll

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle, c#-4.0, ora-01426

I am trying to write a very simple webpage using Visual Studio 2010, .Net 4, C#.  I am using the Oracle DataAccess .DLL and have made a connection to the database just fine.  When I run this code, I get the exception 'ORA-01426: Numeric Overflow."  I am not doing any calculations, and I put the whole thing into a string before I submit the query.  Below is my code sample:

```
string sql = "SELECT * from users.training WHERE per_id_no = " + strIdNo;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        try
        {
            Label1.Visible = false;
            //Read data from the database
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // C#
            dr.Read();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If per_id_no is a varchar2 data type then you probably need to put the value in single quotes.
string sql = "SELECT * from users.training WHERE per_id_no = '" + strIdNo + "'";

Of course, I entirely agree with @jgauffin, in which case I think the query should look like this
string sql = "SELECT * from users.training WHERE per_id_no = '@id'";
But I am pretty sure in Oracle the paramter should be :id and not @id which I believe is SQL Server syntax.

Anyway, HTH
Harv

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much, I have been looking for days for an answer to this, and I knew it would come down to my ignorance of basic Oracle/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Never include parameters directly into the SQL statement. Use named arguments instead:

```
    string sql = "SELECT * from users.training WHERE per_id_no = @id";
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) 
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        //syntax differs between different providers
        cmd.Parameters.Add("id", strIdNo); 

        try
        {
            Label1.Visible = false;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am brand new to using Oracle with .NET, so once I get this working I will look at implementing your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`strIdNo` may be too large for the type that would contain it.  Check to be sure it doesn't need to be quoted (to convert it into a string).  Also check the type of the `per_id_no` column to make sure it is the type you expect (and that `strIdNo` can fit in it).